# Selective output from SoX stats option?

Tags: bash, parsing, sox

I'm using Kubuntu to run SoX. I have the following code to get info from sound files:

```
for file in *.mp3; do echo -e '\n--------------------\n'$file'\n'; sox $file -n stats; done > stats.txt 2>&1 | tail -1
```

It produces output that looks like this:

```
--------------------
soundfile_name.mp3

DC offset  -0.000287
Min level  -0.585483
Max level   0.572299
Pk lev dB      -4.65
RMS lev dB    -19.55
RMS Pk dB     -12.98
RMS Tr dB     -78.44
Crest factor    5.56
Flat factor     0.00
Pk count           2
Bit-depth      29/29
Num samples     628k
Length s      14.237
Scale max   1.000000
Window s       0.050
```

Could someone amend the command to limit the output so that it looks like this?

```
--------------------
soundfile_name.mp3

Pk lev dB      -4.65
RMS lev dB    -19.55
RMS Pk dB     -12.98
RMS Tr dB     -78.44
```

thanks

Comment: What is `| tail -1` for?

Comment: Thanks. I actually don't know. It seems the same with or without it.

Comment: Done. Was going to come back and accept the answer but it's disappeared. Confused,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the lines of interest have the word "dB" in common, you could filter SoX output with `grep -w dB`:

```
for file in *.mp3; do echo -e '\n--------------------\n'$file'\n'; sox $file -n stats | grep -w dB; done > stats.txt 2>&1
```

Resulting content of `stats.txt`:

```
--------------------
soundfile_name.mp3

Pk lev dB      -4.65
RMS lev dB    -19.55
RMS Pk dB     -12.98
RMS Tr dB     -78.44
```